# Using jQuery tableSorter on dynamically modified table

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using the jQuery tableSorter plugin on a page.

Unfortunatley, the table that is being sorted is dynamically modified, and when I sort after adding an element, the  element disappears, restoring the table to the state that it was in when the tableSorter was created.

Is there any way that i can force tableSorter to rescan the page so that these new elements are sorted properly?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe you can trigger an update using something like:

```
$(table).trigger("update")
```

Comment: Just a comment, i need to use the code like this: $("#table_id").trigger("update");

Answer (score 14):

Seems you are correct.

```
$(table).trigger("update");
$(table).trigger("appendCache");
```

does the trick.

As a note, the tablesorter API changed at some point, so these things got changed, as well as the event binding.  My biggest hangup was trying to figure out why some things worked and others did not, and it was due to having a wrong version of the plugin, despite there being no obvious distinction.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Without the "appendCache" part, I can only sort in one direction (1st click sorts, 2nd does nothing), as in Josh's answer. But with it, everything works as expected. Note that if the update is occurring in another code block from where you created your tablesorter object, you can just recreate it there. Suppose your tablesorter tabe has id "ts".  Do `$("#ts").tablesorter().trigger("update");` and same for `appendCache`. Or: `$table = $("#ts").tablesorter(); $table.trigger("update"); $table.trigger("appendCache");`

Comment: On the other hand, I just found out that this answer will not work if you just deleted a row. I'm not sure you actually need to do anything if you delete a row.

Answer (score 4):

The `$(table).trigger("update");` throws error

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined
```

So, there is a jquery function `.ajaxStop()` where `tablesorter()` is called. Do not call tablesorter in `.ready()`

```
    jQuery(document).ajaxStop(function(){
      jQuery("#table_name").tablesorter();
    })
```

which did the job

Answer (score 2):

For those Newbies like me who are facing issue with sorting dynamic generated table, here is the solution.
The answer previously given are correct, but where do you place this command?

```
$('#tableId').tablesorter().trigger('update');
```

You need to place it as soon as you've appended the data to the table.
Ex in my case

```
var tableData = "<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></thead><tbody><tr><td>Izaki</td><td>24</td><tr><tr><td>Serizawa</td><td>25</td></tr>";
$('#tableId').html('tableData');
$('#tableId').tablesorter().trigger('update');
```