# jQuery AJAX tableSorter

Tags: jquery, ajax, tablesorter

I have table a select box and change event for my AJAX call with tablesorter plugin. It does not seem to apply tablesorter more than once. After AJAX success, the sorter functionalities do not get applied to the newly loaded html elements. Below is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#policies').dataTable();
                $('#PolicyCategory').live('change',function(){
                var policy = $('#PolicyCategory').val();
                var form_data = {
                            category_id: policy,
                            ajax: '1'       
                        };


                        $.ajax({
                            url: "http://coverbuddy.favstay.com/users/category_ajax",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "html",
                            cache: false,
                            data : form_data,
                            success: function(data){
                                //console.log();
                                //alert(data);
                                $('#policies').html(data);
                                $("#policies").trigger("update");
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
```

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried executing dataTable again in the success callback? $('#policies').dataTable();

Comment: yes I did not working...

Comment: You can actually chain functions with jQuery. Try this in your success callback: $('#policies').html(data).dataTable().trigger('update'); You probably need to have updated the policies element with the new HTML prior to executing dataTable() on it

Comment: Sorry I tried this method just now but it's not working....

Comment: Did you try hooking into 'error:' or 'complete:' to make sure its' working?

Comment: I tried both but still not working...

Answer (score 0):

Try including an "appendCache" trigger - from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247305/using-jquery-tablesorter-on-dynamically-modified-table):

```
$('#policies')
  .html(data)
  .trigger("update")
  .trigger("appendCache");
```