# Tablesorter, multiple search in the same column

Tags: tablesorter

I'm trying to make a multiple search in a same column. For example if I've a colors columns  and I search: "red, yell" the tablesorter should show all the red and yellow rows. I've been searching for it and I've tried to reuse the code to create my own searcher, but any result obtained. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

I'm using Jquery 1.8.30 and jquery UI 1.9

```
<script src="~/Content/tablesorter-master/js/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="~/Content/tablesorter-master/js/jquery.tablesorter.combined.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="~/Content/tablesorter-master/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="~/Content/tablesorter-master/js/widgets/widget-columnSelector.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="~/Content/tablesorter-master/js/widgets/widget-filter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="~/Content/tablesorter-master/js/widgets/widget-headerTitles.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="~/Content/tablesorter-master/js/widgets/widget-output.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="~/Content/tablesorter-master/js/widgets/widget-reorder.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="~/Content/jquery-ui-daterangepicker-0.4.3/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $("#multiPicker").daterangepicker({
            datepickerOptions: {
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                initialText: '@ViewData("SelectPeriod")'
            }
        });

        // these default equivalents were obtained from a table of equivalents
        // provided by sugar.js sorting alogrithms: http://sugarjs.com/sorting
        $.tablesorter.characterEquivalents = {
            'a': '\u00e1\u00e0\u00e2\u00e3\u00e4\u0105\u00e5', // áàâãäaå
            'A': '\u00c1\u00c0\u00c2\u00c3\u00c4\u0104\u00c5', // ÁÀÂÃÄAÅ
            'c': '\u00e7\u0107\u010d', // çcc
            'C': '\u00c7\u0106\u010c', // ÇCC
            'e': '\u00e9\u00e8\u00ea\u00eb\u011b\u0119', // éèêëee
            'E': '\u00c9\u00c8\u00ca\u00cb\u011a\u0118', // ÉÈÊËEE
            'i': '\u00ed\u00ec\u0130\u00ee\u00ef\u0131', // íìIîïi
            'I': '\u00cd\u00cc\u0130\u00ce\u00cf', // ÍÌIÎÏ
            'o': '\u00f3\u00f2\u00f4\u00f5\u00f6\u014d', // óòôõöo
            'O': '\u00d3\u00d2\u00d4\u00d5\u00d6\u014c', // ÓÒÔÕÖO
            'ss': '\u00df', // ß (s sharp)
            'SS': '\u1e9e', // ? (Capital sharp s)
            'u': '\u00fa\u00f9\u00fb\u00fc\u016f', // úùûüu
            'U': '\u00da\u00d9\u00db\u00dc\u016e' // ÚÙÛÜU
        };

        // modify the above defaults as follows
        $.extend($.tablesorter.characterEquivalents, {
            "ae": "\u00e6", // expanding characters æ Æ
            "AE": "\u00c6",
            "oe": "\u00f6\u0153", // œ Œ
            "OE": "\u00d6\u0152",
            "d": "\u00f0",  // Eth (ð Ð)
            "D": "\u00d0",
            "o": "\u00f3\u00f2\u00f4\u00f5", // remove ö because it's in the oe now
            "O": "\u00d3\u00d2\u00d4\u00d5"  // remove Ö because it's in the OE now
        });

        // overflow table
        $('.wrapperOverflow table').tablesorter({
            debug: true, //Firebug (console) needed --> /docs/example-option-debug.html
            //showProcessing: true, //has bugs --> /docs/example-option-show-processing.html
            sortMultiSortKey: 'altKey', //Click to sort any column header, then hold down the alt key and select a second column. Continue selecting columns as desired.
            widthFixed: true,
            widgets: ['filter', 'reorder', 'columnSelector'],
            widgetOptions: {
                sortList: [[3, 1]], //[[column, asc(0)/desc(1)]]
                widgets: ['filter', 'reorder', 'resizable'],
                ignoreCase: true, // if false, upper case sorts BEFORE lower case
                filter_columnFilters: true,
                filter_liveSearch: true,
                filter_saveFilters: true,
                filter_filteredRow: 'filtered',
                filter_functions: true,
                reorder_axis: 'xy', // 'x' or 'xy'
                reorder_delay: 100,
                reorder_helperClass: 'tablesorter-reorder-helper',
                reorder_helperBar: 'tablesorter-reorder-helper-bar',
                columnSelector_container: $('#columnSelector'),
                columnSelector_columns: {},
                columnSelector_saveColumns: true,
                columnSelector_layout: '<label><input type="checkbox">{name}</label>',
                columnSelector_name: 'data-selector-name',
                columnSelector_mediaquery: true,
                columnSelector_mediaqueryName: '@ViewData("Auto")' + ': ',
                columnSelector_mediaqueryState: true,
                columnSelector_priority: 'data-priority',
                columnSelector_cssChecked: 'checked'
            }
        });

        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247305/using-jquery-tablesorter-on-dynamically-modified-table
        $('.wrapperOverflow table').trigger("update");
        $('.wrapperOverflow table').trigger("appendCache");

        //Filters style
        $(".tablesorter-filter").addClass("searchStyle");

        //Reset button
        $('#butReset').click(function () {

            var thereIsSearch = false

            $(".searchStyle").each(function () {
                $('input[type=search]').val('');
                thereIsSearch = true
            });

            if (thereIsSearch == true) {
                var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
                e.which = 13; //choose the one you want
                e.keyCode = 13;
                $('.searchStyle').trigger(e);
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html), then the [filter widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html) will accept "OR" searches using a vertical bar `|` or the word "or" surrounded by spaces `or`. [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/567/):

```
$.tablesorter.setFilters( $('table'), ['', 'Aaron|Peter' ], true );
```

or

```
$.tablesorter.setFilters( $('table'), ['', '', 'Hood or Parker' ], true );
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer but is not working for me. I've been looking all the docs attached in the fork and I haven't been able to do it work. For that question I did ask. And looking your example I believe I haven't left nothing. The only different things are the css  (I'm using my own for the table) and that I'm applying more filters.

Comment: Here you can see an image of my table and the results: http://subefotos.com/ver/?0793a6631edc53538e76e5e051367942o.jpg

Comment: When I've said filters before I mean widgets.

Comment: If the text isn't matching, make sure to add a "filter-match" class to the header, otherwise the search looks for an exact match.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. At last I've remade the view and now is working fine. I don't know what I had forgotten but didn't works, now does it. Sorry for the inconveniences.